# image carousel using transform property

Tags: javascript, css, dom, events, scroll

example code: - https://jsfiddle.net/dy1vk40f/

I want to make a image carousel feature, I implemented everything with two button :- `forward` and `backword` to scroll according to the buttons. I have used `scrollcontainer.style.transform =` `translate3d(-250px, 0px, 0px);` to move the images forward and vice versa. Now I want to implement a feature where when the mouse is clicked on the container and drag to left or right, I want to again change the transform property. But I am struggling to do it properly.

I have this code, but it gives a very glitchy scroll and I don't think its the right way to do it. Is there any other, it would be great help if anyone can help

````js
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

scrollcontainer.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDown = true;
    startX = e.pageX;
    console.log(startX);
});

scrollcontainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  isDown = false;
});

scrollcontainer.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  isDown = false;
});

scrollcontainer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const x = e.pageX;

  const walk = (x - startX) * 3;
  scrollcontainer.style.transform = `translate3d(${walk}px, 0px, 0px)`;
  console.log({walk, startX});
  console.log('gg');
});```
````

Comment: Can you include the HTML and CSS for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably via [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: I have shared the example code for this

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, you don't need translate.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView